# Mocking models with a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

I'm attempting to create a Mockery of `CustomObject` then chain the retrieval of `OtherObject` onto it using something identical to

```
$this->CustomObject->with('OtherObject')->get();
```

I can't seem to figure out how to mock this `->get()` at the end there. I'm mocking both of those models in my constructor method `['Eloquent', 'OtherObject', 'CustomObject']`. If I remove the `->get()` everything runs smoothly and my tests pass (aside from the php errors the view is then giving me, but those don't matter if the test is working correctly).

What I currently have is this:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('with')->once()->with('OtherObject');
$this->app->instance('CustomObject', $this->mock);
```

What should I be doing to mock this?

Edit: I have specifically attempted `->andReturn($this->mock)` which only tells me that on the mocked object there is no get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return an instance of your mock to make the next chaining call (`->get()`) to work

```
$this->mock
     ->shouldReceive('with')
     ->once()
     ->with('OtherObject')
     ->andReturn($this->mock);
```

Comment: I had tried specifically that and it still says that I cannot use the public member get on a non-object.

Comment: I don't recall what my issue was exactly at this point but your method is most certainly correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mockery::self()` to define chained expectations with arguments.

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('with')
    ->once()->with('OtherObject')
    ->andReturn(m::self())->getMock()
    ->shouldReceive('get')->once()
    ->andReturn($arrayOfMocks);
```

In some cases you may need to split it up into two mocks:

```
$mockQuery = m::mock();
$this->mock->shouldReceive('with')
    ->once()->with('OtherObject')
    ->andReturn($mockQuery);
$mockQuery->shouldReceive('get')->once()
    ->andReturn($arrayOfMocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have it. It seems that the previous answer and my attempts were very close. The largest issue with using these is that a method is being called on the return object. If this isn't the best way to do this, I hope someone will correct me though.

```
$other_object = Mockery::mock('OtherObject');
$other_object->shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn(new OtherObject);

$this->mock->shouldReceive('with')
           ->once()
           ->with('OtherObject')
           ->andReturn($other_object);

$this->app->instance('CustomObject', $this->mock);
```

and removing `OtherObject' from the constructor method.